# Loop does showpoint on wrong variables

Tags: c++, loops, buffer, average, fixed

When I get my first line of output for the average it shows the three numbers (ie. v1, v2, v3) like this "30, 54, 99" basically with no showpoint but the next four lines in the loop will show the next three random numbers like this "44.00".

I'm trying to get my output like this

The average of  75  91  68 is: 78.00

The average of  85  76  93 is: 84.67

The average of  67  21  11 is: 33.00

My first line comes out but the other four do not. I try clearing the buffer with cin.clear and cin.ignore but to no avail. Any ideas?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

double average(int num1, int num2, int num3);

int main() {

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        
    double v1 = rand() % 100 + 1;
        
    double v2 = rand() % 100 + 1;
        
    double v3 = rand() % 100 + 1;
        
    double avg = average(v1, v2, v3);
        
    cout << "The average of " 
     << v1 << " " << v2 << " " << v3 
     << " is: " << fixed << showpoint 
     << setprecision(2) << avg 
     << endl;
    }     
return 0;   
}

/// for loop to find the average

double average(int num1, int num2, int num3)
{
   double avg = (num1 + num2 + num3) / 3;

   return avg;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The **problem is** you're passing the argument to function `average` as `int` instead of double. The **solution** would be to just change the parameters of function `average` from `int` to `double` :

```
//note the parameters are changed to double instead of int
double average(double num1, double num2, double num3)
{
   double avg = (num1 + num2 + num3) / 3;

   return avg;

}
```

Also do change the forward declaration also to

```
double average(double num1, double num2, double num3);
```

Also, you can use `static_cast<int>` to get the output in your desired form. So change your `cout` statement to:

```
cout << "The average of " 
     << static_cast<int>(v1) << " " << static_cast<int>(v2) << " " << static_cast<int>(v3) 
     << " is: " << fixed << showpoint 
     << setprecision(2) << avg 
     << endl;
```

The output of the complete program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/xoPaElu5j) which looks like:

```
The average of 84 87 78 is: 83.00
The average of 16 94 36 is: 48.67
The average of 87 93 50 is: 76.67
The average of 22 63 28 is: 37.67
The average of 91 60 64 is: 71.67
```

Answer (score 1):

just convert your double v1 v2 v3 to int

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

double average(int num1, int num2, int num3);

int main() {

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {

        double v1 = rand() % 100 + 1;

        double v2 = rand() % 100 + 1;

        double v3 = rand() % 100 + 1;

        double avg = average(v1, v2, v3);

        cout << "The average of "
            << (int)v1 << " " << (int)v2 << " " << (int)v3
            << " is: " << fixed << showpoint
            << setprecision(2) << avg
            << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

/// for loop to find the average

double average(int num1, int num2, int num3)
{
    double avg = (num1 + num2 + num3) / 3;

    return avg;

}
```

OUTPUT

```
The average of 42 68 35 is: 48.00
The average of 1 70 25 is: 32.00
The average of 79 59 63 is: 67.00
The average of 65 6 46 is: 39.00
The average of 82 28 62 is: 57.00
```